# Is there a high end expensive photo transfer cable for my Olympus E-520 DSLR to PC?

Tags: olympus

Is there a high end expensive USB 2.0 photo transfer cable for my Olympus E-520 DSLR to my windows 7 PC? What type of USB cable does my Olympus E-520 take to transfer data to my PC?

Comment: USB is USB, that's the whole point of it.

Comment: To be fair, there are several USB connector types.

Comment: Check your manual or google the camera specs.

Comment: @fkraiem I've always found the **U** in USB to be a lie. With the myriad connector types, sometimes proprietary (especially in the point-and-click world), it seems far from universal.

Comment: @scottbb The USB Implementers Forum doesn't forbid having  proprietary connectors on a cable as long as the end that bears the USB logo meets the standard.  The smaller connectors you find on very compact cameras are there because the standard USB connectors have mechanical and real estate needs  that often can't be met on those kinds of projects.

Comment: @Blrfl Understood. From a consumer perspective, however, it is still confusing. When you have dig through a box-o-cables, that reasoning isn't very comforting. USB-OTG, USB-C, and Thunderbolt 3 will go a long way to remediate those issues, but it will take a long time before they are "universally" adopted across devices such as cameras.

Answer (score 1):

The images are transferred digitally, bit-for-bit. A "high quality" cable isn't going to make any difference. You just need a working USB cable, with the right connectors at each end. There are many, inexpensive options widely available.

Answer (score 1):

Camera makers seem to have been among the last electronics manufacturers to completely adopt standard USB cables.

Olympus point-and-shoots in particular took a long time to come around to standard USB cables. The camera-end of the cable has a proprietary connector, which is also used for non-USB connections such as wired remote shutter release, A/V breakout, etc.

I have seen the cable your camera uses referred to as "CB-USB6". I don't believe that's an industry-standard name, and I don't know if that's how Olympus refers to the cable. But searching for "Olympus E-520 replacement USB cable" returns several product links with the same cable:

- [USB CB-USB5 CB-USB6 Data / Photo Transfer Cable Cord Lead Wire for Olympus Camera](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0099ZRACS) (Amazon.com)
- [NiceTQ Replacement USB Data Sync Cable Cord For Olympus E-330/E-410/E-420/E-450/E-500/E-510/E-520/E-600](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N949IIS) (Amazon.com)
- [USB Download Cable (CB-USB6) for Olympus...](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GNU138Y) (Amazon.com)

Note the camera-end connector: it is not a standard USB A/mini-A/micro-A or B/mini-B/micro-B connector.

[image]

---

As far as "high-end expensive USB 2.0 cable", I'm not sure what you mean there. Being non-standard, this cable is what it is.